# Unable to start .bat script under Windows 7

Tags: batch-file, windows-7

This is strange: in general, .bat scripts work fine on this machine. So the PATH variable is fine.

However, I have one script that creates the error message
--> `'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe\' is not recognized as an internal ....`

Here is the one-line script:
--> `@echo %1 | "C:\Program Files\putty\PSFTP.exe" -pw xxx User@Host`

This script is working fine on two other Windows 7 machines, just not on mine.
Any ideas what to check?

Comment: What is the output of `reg query "HKCR\batfile\shell\open\command"` on the machine that isn't working?  Does your `-pw xxx` argument contain an ampersand, pipe, or other character that might be causing confusion?  Does it make a difference to rename your `.bat` script with a `.cmd` extension?  If that does make a difference, then your `.bat` association has a trailing backslash where it shouldn't.  Check the subkeys under `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.bat`.  Or if you just want to reset to defaults, [see this answer](http://superuser.com/a/54280/204705).

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible you are using a 64bit version of Windows?. The path may need to be set to point to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Putty"

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the problem had nothing to do with the specific command. Even a 
    dir | dir
from the command line threw the same error. 
I did find the solution here: 
    https://superuser.com/questions/557387/pipe-not-working-in-cmd-exe-on-windows-7 
Problem was the environment variable ComSpec; somehow it had a bad character in the field. I removed that darn back-slash and all is fine.

Thanks for looking at my problem.